# Flask and Celery FileUpload returns BufferedRandom Error

Tags: flask, celery, pickle

I'm trying to do a simple file upload and getting an error:
**kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type FileStorage is not JSON serializable**

My code:

```
@flask_app.post('/upload')
def upload_post():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    if uploaded_file.filename != '':

        result =  upload_file_task.delay(uploaded_file)
        return {"result_id": result.id}
        #return jsonify({'status':'OK', 'filename': uploaded_file.filename})
    else:
        return jsonify({'status':'No file'})

@shared_task(bind=True, ignore_result=False)
def upload_file_task(self, file):
    try:
        # Save the file
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)      
        file.save(os.path.join('tmp/', filename))
        return 'File uploaded successfully'
    except Exception as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

I've tried adding **serializer = 'pickle'** to the task annotation but then I get this error:
**kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedRandom' object**

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to encode the object and pass it as JSON to the Celery task and then decode it in the task. I followed this code [How to use Celery to upload files in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116738/how-to-use-celery-to-upload-files-in-django)